# Ember test - Failed: Calling set on destroyed object

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, ember-cli

I'm currently trying to get started with writing tests (I know, I know, I should have done that before I wrote the application), but I'm currently stuck trying to test the login functionality.

Here is the test:

```
/* jshint expr:true */
import {
  describe,
  it,
  beforeEach,
  afterEach
} from 'mocha';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';

describe('Integration: Authentication', function() {
  var application;

  beforeEach(function() {
    application = startApp();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  });

  it('User can sign in', function() {
    visit('/signin').then(function() {
      fillIn('input[name="identification"]', 'username');
      fillIn('input[name="password"]', 'password');
      click('button[type="submit"]');
      andThen(function() {
        expect(currentPath()).to.equal('welcome');
      })
    });
  });
});
```

Im getting this error:

`Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object (http://localhost:7357/a
ssets/vendor.js:19994)`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code you are trying to test?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe you're trying to call set on a destroyed object. The most common case is an `Ember.run` scheduling something to be run in the future, and the object, such as a component, is torn down before it runs. The ways to avoid this are (1) check for the object being destroyed before calling set on it or (2) cancelling the `Ember.run` request in the object's `willDestroy` hook.

Comment: Im wondering if its because that the 'content' has changed and so the binding is 'gone'. We start on a signin page and this is the base of the test, but when clicking the login button, the page and state of the application changes. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @QuantumLicht it's a basic simple auth implementation.

Comment: having the same problem here, any fix?

Comment: @torazaburo - It would be handy to know which object it is trying to destroy.

Comment: If you run the tests in the browser (`ember test --screen`), you can see the screen trace and track it down.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `ember test --server` obviously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141822/uncaught-error-assertion-failed-calling-set-on-destroyed-object)